# How do I set a sheet's chart series' point shape?

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a chart in a Google Sheets document, based on data from another sheet.

When adding the various series into the chart, how do I set that series' point shape (star, circle etc.) in the Google Sheets API? I can change its colour, but not its shape, based on the below API documentation?

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#basicchartseries

Comment: It can be done with Google Apps Script, by calling [`EmbeddedChartBuilder#setOption`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setOption(String,Object)), to manipulate the `series[<index>].pointShape` value(s), but indeed it appears you are unable to manipulate the gviz chart spec via Google Sheets API.